# Is it possible to resolve a value to a color using echarts visualMap from the "outside", as api?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

For my custom report, I need to use just the Visual Map component from `apache echarts` library and "synchronize" it with my custom report which does not uses `echarts`. The problem I face is that I do not know how to resolve values in my custom report to colors from `echarts`' `visualMap`. Is it possible to get a color from a continuous `visualMap` component by providing a value from a custom report? Any suggestions on the  interpolation type that `echarts' visualMap` uses in order to employ `d3-scale-chromatic`, for example, as a workaround?
Thanks.